# ClassCastException HikariCPConnectionProvider cannot be cast to Hibernate ConnectionProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, connection, hikaricp, pooling

I am trying my hands on `HikariCP` for the first time. I am facing following `ClassCastException`.

ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider cannot be cast to org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider

UPDATE: I have tried com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider also, and get the same exception.

Here is my config from `persistence.xml`

```
<properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="30000" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user" value="dbusr" />
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password" value="pwd" />
    </properties>
```

I am using following Hibernate and HikariCP versions.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry that I am responding to my own question after so long.
I was facing this issue because I tried to upgrade various hibernate and hikari library versions, which caused my target folder of maven build to have multiple versions of hibernate and hikari causing wrong versions to get picked up. The issue was resolved after cleaning up target and fixing few pom files.
Hikari has been doing good since then and also it is very helpful in detecting leaking connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" 
       value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider" />
```

by

```
property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"  
       value="com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider"
```

Also see [Hibernate 5 + HikariCP + MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821574/hibernate-5-hikaricp-mysql) for setup of another person using Hikari with Hibernate5.

Comment: I get the same ClassCastException with com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider also. :(

Comment: The dependency is clearly for org.hibernate, why would you think of changing to com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate?  did you try that?

Comment: @BodhiOne my answer was 7 years ago; possibly it's different nowadays. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/53153247/449347 there seems to be a "official" hibernate provider now; pretty sure there wasn't back when I looked at this, but so long ago I have mostly forgotten :-)