# Hikari connection is not available and unexpected multiple pool issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hikaricp, connectionexception

In my companies project, we are using Hikari for connection pool management.
[Hibernate 4.3.5 + Spring 4 + Java 1.8]
Below is the configuration

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class=com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle=5
hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout=60
hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
```

We are facing below problem two problem

1. For some reason, Hikari is creating 2 connection pool HikariPool-1 and HikariPool-2.
2. Only HikariPool-2 is being used and even that is giving error `Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms` after some time

### Below are the logs of Hikari initiation and the error of request timed out.

```
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider -- Configuring HikariCP
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- HikariPool-1 - configuration:
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- allowPoolSuspension.............false
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- autoCommit......................true
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- catalog.........................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- connectionInitSql...............null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- connectionTestQuery............."SELECT 1"
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- connectionTimeout...............30000
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- dataSource......................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- dataSourceClassName............."com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- dataSourceJNDI..................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- dataSourceProperties............{user=walletadmin, url=jdbc:mysql://111.111.11.11:3306/database, 
password=<masked>}
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- driverClassName.................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- healthCheckProperties...........{}
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- healthCheckRegistry.............null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- idleTimeout.....................10800
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- initializationFailFast..........true
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- isolateInternalQueries..........false
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- jdbcUrl.........................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- leakDetectionThreshold..........0
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- maxLifetime.....................1800000
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- maximumPoolSize.................50
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- metricRegistry..................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- metricsTrackerFactory...........null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- minimumIdle.....................5
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- password........................<masked>
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- readOnly........................false
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- registerMbeans..................false
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- scheduledExecutorService........null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- threadFactory...................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- transactionIsolation............null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- username........................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- validationTimeout...............5000
[2018-11-05 15:18:02] - [] - INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Started.
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider -- HikariCP Configured
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider -- Configuring HikariCP



[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- HikariPool-2 - configuration:
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- allowPoolSuspension.............false
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- autoCommit......................true
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- catalog.........................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- connectionInitSql...............null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- connectionTestQuery............."SELECT 1"
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- connectionTimeout...............30000
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- dataSource......................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- dataSourceClassName............."com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- dataSourceJNDI..................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- dataSourceProperties............{user=walletadmin, url=jdbc:mysql://111.111.11.11:3306/database, 
password=<masked>}
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- driverClassName.................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- healthCheckProperties...........{}
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- healthCheckRegistry.............null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- idleTimeout.....................10800
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- initializationFailFast..........true
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- isolateInternalQueries..........false
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- jdbcUrl.........................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- leakDetectionThreshold..........0
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- maxLifetime.....................1800000
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- maximumPoolSize.................50
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- metricRegistry..................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- metricsTrackerFactory...........null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- minimumIdle.....................5
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- password........................<masked>
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- poolName........................"HikariPool-2"
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- readOnly........................false
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- registerMbeans..................false
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- scheduledExecutorService........null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- threadFactory...................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- transactionIsolation............null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- username........................null
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig -- validationTimeout...............5000
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-2 - Started.
[2018-11-05 15:18:03] - [] - DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider -- HikariCP Configured
```

---

```
[2018-11-04 11:00:30] - [] - ERROR com.agwallet.serviceImpl.InstantGiftCardAcceptServiceImpl --  Exception getting from ================= instantGiftVirtualCardAccept() =============Could not open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:234)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.findAllPendingGiftVirtualCard(Unknown Source)
        at com.agwallet.serviceImpl.InstantGiftCardAcceptServiceImpl.instantGiftVirtualCardAccept(InstantGiftCardAcceptServiceImpl.java:57)
        at com.agwallet.jobs.InstantActivationForGiftCardJob.instantGiftVirtualCardRequest(InstantActivationForGiftCardJob.java:29)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:364)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.getResultList(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:454)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-2 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider.getConnection(HikariConnectionProvider.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
        ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Comment: My guess you yourself are constructing a `DataSource` and next you configure Hibernate to do the same. If you configure the `DataSource` yourself in Spring and inject that into the `SessionFactory` or `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` you shouldn't configure the `hibernate.connection.provider_class`.

Comment: What is your hibernate version?

Comment: @user7294900 Hibernate 4.3.5 + Spring 4 + Java 1.8

Comment: Can you consider upgrade to 4.3.6? As of Hibernate 4.3.6 there is an official ConnectionProvider class from Hibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade Hibernate from 4.3.5 to 4.3.6, there's a official ConnectionProvider for Hibernate:

> UPDATE : Hibernate 4.3.6+
> As of Hibernate 4.3.6 there is an official ConnectionProvider class from Hibernate, which should be used instead of the HikariCP implementation. The class is called org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider.

So you should replace `com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider` with `org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider`

See also [MySQL Hikari Configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration)